# For loop show nothing any result in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, for-loop, advanced-custom-fields

I'm developing an own theme in Wordpress and using Advanced Custom Fields to display a header and a text in 6 small sections.

I named them `text_header_1` and then increased the number all the way to 6.

So I figured that I can loop the right result out, but it doesn't work. I don't know if ordinary `for loops` is possible to do in Wordpress?

Either way, here is my code that failed:

```
            <div class="media">


            <?php

            for($i = 1; $i > 7; $i++) {

                $numberHeader = 'text_header_' . $i ;
                $numberText = 'text_' . $i;

                $textHeader = get_field($numberHeader);
                $text = get_field($numberText);

            ?>

                <div class="pull-left">
                        <span class="fa-stack fa-2x">
                              <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x text-primary"></i>
                              <i class="fa fa-tree fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                        </span>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">

                    <h4 class="media-heading"><?php echo $textHeader; ?></h4>
                    <p><?php echo $text; ?></p>
                </div>

            <?php } ?>

        </div>
```

The result of this is nothing. I get no errors, just an empty div. 
Do I need to use something else than a for loop? Maybe a while? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is never executing because you are checking while $i is greater than 7, which it never is because it starts at 1.  Change this:

```
for($i = 1; $i > 7; $i++) {
```

to this:

```
for($i = 1; $i < 7; $i++) {
```